# Matplotlib.pyplot: 2x4 and 1 plot in one picture

Tags: python, matplotlib

here is my problem: I have 8 sets of measurment data. On half of the picture i want to show my data as maps using plt.imshow, on the other half i want to have 1 picture where i show the average value. I have several frames per data set. Here is a picture of what i want and my code as far i got it (For simplicity i just took three data sets):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

NrMax = [473,490,140]

for frame in range(0,200): #Nr of temporal frames 

    for _ in range(0,3): #Loop over data set. Distinguish, because not all experiments have the same length. 


        if(_ == 0):

            if(frame > NrMax[_]):
                data_temp = data10ug[NrMax[_]]
            else:
                data_temp = data10ug[frame]

        elif(_ == 1):
            if(frame > NrMax[_]):
                data_temp = data25ug[NrMax[_]]
            else:
                data_temp = data25ug[frame]

        elif(_ == 2):
            if(frame > NrMax[_]):
                data_temp = data1000ug[NrMax[_]]
            else:
                data_temp = data1000ug[frame]


        data_temp = data_temp**2



        # Opt out
        #---------------------    


        plt.subplot(2,4,_+1)
        var_map = plt.imshow(data_temp, vmin = 0, vmax = 0.025, origin = 'lower')
        var_map.set_cmap('bwr')
        plt.title(titles[_])
        if(colorbar == False):
            plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand the significance of different frames. Are you planning to create, e.g., 200 different images reflecting the 200 temporal points?

Anyway, in order to create a layout which might be close to what you want, you might want to use `GridSpec` for the subplots

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

# create some random data
dat = [ np.random.random((10,10)) for _ in range(8) ]

# create the figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[12,4])

# create two gridspecs adjacent to each other (left and right)
gs1 = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(2, 4, left=.1, right=.55)
gs2 = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1, left=.65, right=.9)

# define the plot axes and add the images
imgaxes = []
for i in range(8):
    imgaxes.append(plt.subplot(gs1[i / 4, i % 4]))
    imgaxes[i].imshow(dat[i])

# add the graph axis
grax = plt.subplot(gs2[0,0])
grax.plot(np.random.random(100))
```

This code creates

[image]

You will of course want to change the positions and scales, maybe do something with the axes, etc. Tweaking the subplot positions should be easy enough by using the keyword arguments for `GridSpec` or by using the `gridspec.update`.